# Coding Dot Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to code a group of dots, where by "group of dots" I mean a solid (or dashed) line enclosing one or more dots?  For example, a circle with three identical solid dots (inside) is "a group of three dots".  Additionally, it would be helpful if one could have nested groups, as well as other shapes such as squares, triangles, etc.

Comment: How are the dots supposed to be arranged? Are they randomly placed within the grouping circle or arranged in a pattern?

Comment: Do the enclosing path has to be always a circle or does it have to have the same shape as the inner elements?

Comment: Generally speaking, a circle or an ellipse is the shape that encloses a group, and there is no particular arrangement pattern required.

Comment: @Clark I've updated my answer. Is it something like that what you need?

Comment: Perfect!  Awesome...ThanX!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Update

An improved version allowing for random placement of the inner elements of a group; I also added an example using the `decorations.shapes` library as suggested by **Claudio Fiandrino**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes,shapes.geometric,fit}

\newcommand\Group[4][circle,draw=red]{%
\pgfresetboundingbox
\begin{scope}[scale=0.3,transform shape]
\foreach \i in {1,...,#2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\x{rnd*#2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\y{rnd*#2}
  \node[#3] (\i) at (\x,\y) {};
\end{scope}
\node[circle,#1,fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east)] (#4) {};
}
\tikzset{
paint/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!50}, 
decorate with/.style={
  decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=#1,shape size=2mm}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Group{3}{draw=red,fill=red!20,circle,inner sep=2pt}{a}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
\Group[draw=cyan]{7}{draw=cyan,fill=cyan!60,diamond}{b}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\Group[ellipse,draw=magenta]{6}{draw=none,fill=magenta!60,isosceles triangle}{c}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-4cm]
\Group{3}{draw=red,fill=red!20,circle}{d}
\begin{scope}[yshift=1.5cm]
\Group[draw=orange,ellipse]{5}{draw=orange,fill=orange!60,cylinder}{e}
\end{scope}
\node[draw=olive,circle,fit=(d) (e)] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\useasboundingbox (-0.5,-1) rectangle (2.5,1);
\draw[decorate with=circle,paint=green] 
  (0,0) .. controls (0.5,-3) and (1.5,3).. (2,0);
\node[draw=green!80!black,circle,fit=(current bounding box.north west) (current bounding box.south east)] (f) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One option, using the `shapes.geometric` and `fit` libraries from TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}

\newcommand\Group[4][circle,draw=red]{%
\foreach \i in {1,...,#2}
  \node[#3] (\i) at (\i,0) {};
\node[circle,#1,fit=(1) (#2)] (#4) {};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Group{3}{draw=red,fill=red!20,circle}{a}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\Group[draw=cyan,diamond]{2}{draw=cyan,fill=cyan!60,diamond}{b}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
\Group[rectangle,draw=magenta]{6}{draw=none,fill=magenta!60,diamond}{c}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Group{3}{draw=red,fill=red!20,circle}{d}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\Group[draw=cyan,diamond]{2}{draw=cyan,fill=cyan!60,diamond}{e}
\end{scope}
\node[draw=olive,circle,fit=(d) (e)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\Group` has one optional argument and three mandatory ones:

```
\Group[<options for fitting node>]{<number of inner shapes>}{<options for inner shapes>}{<name>}
```

Comment: +1: you may also add an example with the library `decorations.shapes` (can slow down the quickness, but it exists though).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino good idea. I've updated my answer with such an example. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your question reminds me of TikZ’ `petri` library (which is—besides a few styles—just a custom growth function for trees).

Here are some ideas (the first TikZ picture is taken from the manual), the last example shows the use of the custom growth function without a `place` but with the `fit` library. Of course, any shape can be used for either the “tokens” or the “place”.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{petri,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every place/.style={minimum size=9mm}]
\foreach \x/\y/\tokennumber in {0/2/1,1/2/2,2/2/3,
                                0/1/4,1/1/5,2/1/6,
                                0/0/7,1/0/8,2/0/9}
\node [place,tokens=\tokennumber] at (\x,\y) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every place/.style={shape=rectangle},
                    every token/.style={fill=green!\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild 0!red},
                    token distance={min(3mm,120/\the\tikznumberofchildren mm)}
                    ]
\foreach \x/\y/\tokennumber in {0/2/1,1/2/2,2/2/3,
                                0/1/4,1/1/5,2/1/6,
                                0/0/7,1/0/8,2/0/9}
\node [place,tokens=\tokennumber,fill=blue!\tokennumber 0!green] at (\x,\y) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every token/.style={shape=rectangle,name=t-\the\tikznumberofchildren-\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild}]
\foreach \x/\y/\tokennumber in {2/2/3,
                                2/1/6}
\node [structured tokens={1,...,\tokennumber}] at (\x,\y) {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [fit=(t-3-1)(t-3-2)(t-3-3),draw,fill=blue,circle] {};
\node [fit=(t-6-1)(t-6-6),inner sep=2pt,draw=green,fill=red,thick,circle] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is equally cool.